# Why doesn't "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM" variable take effect?

Tags: cmake

I try to use `gmake` instead of `make` as the build command. So I modify the `CMakeList.txt` as following:

```
......
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM /usr/local/bin/gmake)
......
```

While in `CMakeCache.txt`, `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` is still `/usr/bin/make`:

```
//Path to a program.
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/make
```

How to make "`CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM`" variable take effect?

Comment: `set(... CACHE FORCE)`?

Comment: @arrowd Unfortunately, it reminds me "`set given invalid arguments for CACHE mode.`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

*1:* Set the make command when you call `CMake`: `cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=gmake <the rest of your arguments>`

*2:* Do as @arrowd hinted in the comments, but use the correct syntax: `set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM gmake CACHE FILEPATH "" FORCE)` or `set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM gmake CACHE INTERNAL "")`. The latter will hide the setting from `cmake-gui`.

Both of these assume that `gmake` is in your `PATH`, othwerwise you must specify a full path to `gmake`.